# How to select only not related rows without using HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, having

I have table "Serials" with data as follow:

| Serial | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A00010 | 03.03.2022 | BAD |
| A00010 | 04.03.2022 | GOOD |
| A00011 | 05.03.2022 | BAD |
| A00012 | 06.03.2022 | BAD |

I would like to select only those serial number that their actual status is not GOOD.
So as result I expect only A00011 and A00012. This is because A00010 latest (look on Date) status is GOOD.
Query should return only DISTINCT values (Here I used grouping by Serial).

Only solution I've found is with HAVING clause:

```
SELECT [Serial], MAX([Date]),  MAX([Status])
FROM [Serials]
GROUP BY [Serial]
HAVING MAX([Status]) != 'GOOD'
```

I would prefer to avoid using it as it uses more resources (specially when bigger tables are scanned). Additionally, most of Serials in table will have latest record as GOOD anyway, so current Query will pull almost whole table and then HAVING will just crop most of it. For big table it would be big waste of resources.
So if someone could help me to find the query that will do the same but with WHERE clause only.
Thanks.

Comment: Your current query excludes serials that have Ever had a Good Status (on any date, be it the latest date or the first date, or any in between). Does that mean that a Serial can never go from Good back to Bad? Or is it just a mistake in your code?  Also, what indexes are on the table? And can you add new indexes?

Comment: Do you have a dimension table listing all the serials?  (A table with serial being unique.)

Comment: Answer for Q1:  I would prefer if Query would pick BAD boards that were GOOD before. This would be very unusual, but possible situation.
The problem is, that I cant put [Status] column into GROUP BY because it would make HAVING clause useless. I feel that QUERY is not very good because Ideally [Status] should be aggregated according [Date] - which means that [Status] should be picked from same row where MAX([Date]) was picked. So indeed this is error, but accepted as result of query was as expected.
Answer for Q2: No I don't have table with all the serials as being unique.

Comment: Don't assume that query processor engine will execute your query in sequential steps that reflect the sequential order in which your SQL query is written. The optimizer in the processor is pretty smart and does things quite differently from what you might intuitively expect. Look at the query execution plan!  You are much better off writing the query logically, so that it reflects what you want to do from a logical perspective, and let the processor/optimizer figure out how to execute it.  Then look at the execution plan and make adjustments.

Comment: I second what Charles said. SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative language. The difference is that in declarative languages you're not 'writing a program', you're declaring a logical expression that describes the problem you want to solve. The optimiser then is free to write 'a program' (execution plan) however it sees fit in order to solve that expression. Often you will find the plan is completely different to your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select Serial
From Serials s
Where s.Date = 
   (Select Max(Date) From Serials
        Where Serial = s.Serial) 
   And Status != 'Good'
```

If there can exist more than one record in the table with same Serial and Date, then add the word Distinct

```
Select Distinct Serial
From Serials s
Where s.Date = 
    (Select Max(Date) From Serials
        Where Serial = s.Serial) 
   And Status != 'Good'
```

To also address your request in third comment, (to only select Serials that have previously been Good), just add that as an additional predicate to Where clause:

```
Select Distinct Serial
From Serials s
Where s.Date = 
    (Select Max(Date) From Serials
        Where Serial = s.Serial) 
   And Status != 'Good'
   And exists                  -- This predicate ensures that only 
      (Select * from Serial x   -- previously 'GOOD' serials 
       Where serial = s.Serial  -- will appear
          and Date < (Select Max(Date) From Serials
                      Where Serial = s.Serial) 
          and status = 'GOOD')
```

Basically, what you want to do can be translated directly into SQL:

You want a [distinct] list of those Serials that are a set of the last chronological record of each specific serial, filtered to only include the Not Good ones.
So you create a sub table that only includes the records where the date is the latest date for that serial, then filter it by status to only include the not good ones, then extract the serial value from that table.

Depending on how large the table is, This will work very well (or better) if you have an index on the Date attribute.

Comment: You've embarrassed me :D 
This is so simple, I feel now like old guy with dementia. 

To be accurate - 1st option worked for me very well. Second option is not needed because Date field is rather unique as it's typical datetime and there is no real chance someone will enter two rows with same date.
Third option would probably work either, but only if I would need to pick bad boards that were previously GOOD. It's not the case I just need to pick all boards that are currently not GOOD. Which is done by first of your queries.
Many thanks :)

Comment: Hah!  Not to worry, I would venture that a majority of SQL programmers are not proficient in using subqueries within the other clauses of a parent query, as this is. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the last row for each Serial, and then filter out those rows with a Good Status.

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Serial ORDER BY [date] DESC)   AS serial_row   
  FROM
    serials
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
      serial_row  = 1
  AND status     != 'GOOD'
```

Comment: It would work, but the question is if it's more optimized then HAVING clause.

If you run my Query on the [Serials] Table It would pick three of four rows and HAVING clause will be applied on these three rows only. 
In your proposition, all four rows would be picked anyway then additionally each row would be numbered and then from that temp table, result would be filtered with final SELECT. 
I believe there is no big difference, and if there is it's even less optimal then option with HAVING clause.

Comment: @Amikot40 Modern optimisers are aware that rownumber is monotically increasing, and thus know that once 1 has been reached, there is no need to keep counting up, allowing rows to be skipped (assuming index on Serial, date, status). In your query, the optimiser will keep searching for the possibility of a `'ZZZ'` status.  The alternative is to find the Not `'GOOD'` rows, and determine if its the last row for a serial. That can't be done with a single index.  But, don't trust me or Anyone else. Profile it for yourself. Post explain plans and profiling stats, and ask for options. Always test.

Comment: Thanks for you answers, I didn't use your Query, but I've learned something new - which is always good :)